# How to create a composite caption on Neo4j Grass style file?

Tags: neo4j

For example,

```
"node.Person": {
    "color": "#FF756E",
    "border-color": "#E06760",
    "text-color-internal": "#FFFFFF",
    "caption": "{name}"
  }
```

I want the "Person" to be displayed as the label of the node, and "name" and "age" to be displayed as the attributes of the node. Currently, only 'name' is displayed as the caption.

How to change the code above?

EDITED:

Neo4j people, how did you generate the graphs in the book? Thank you. This is one example below. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by editing the styles. Do this by typing ":style" to the neo browser UI, copy-paste the styles to text editor and just add the fields to the caption in curly brackets e.g.

```
  "node.Person": {
    "defaultCaption": "<id>",
    "diameter": "50px",
    "color": "#A5ABB6",
    "border-color": "#9AA1AC",
    "text-color-internal": "#FFFFFF",
    "caption": "{name} {age}"
  }
```

Would result in showing Person entities with name and age on them.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the [comments of my answer](http://www.google.com/) its not possible. My anwser is as close as you can get.  `"node.MESSAGE": { "caption":"Message name:{NAME}" }`. You can only write directly onto the node. I recommend to use different colours for different labels

Comment: it should be possible. Please take a look at this link: https://neo4j.com/blog/5-big-small-things-love-neo4j-2-2/, "composite caption". It's too old though, neo4j, 2.2.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that if I have a few more attributes of a node, then it's going to be messy. It can't nicely put "key:value" pairs on each individual line.

Comment: In chapter 4 they are just saying that you can also add some text to the captions and combine multiple properties. I'm sorry but its not possible. I also had this Problem a while ago. Maybe just use the values and get used to the order of values like:`"node.FRIEND": { "caption":"{name};{surname};{age};{hobby}" }`

Comment: Yeah. That may have to be the case. But anyway, I specifically asked one question for the "Neo4j people". Hopefully the author of the book can have a chance to answer the question. Thanks.